# Which is the better option Share or Post button?

Tags: website-design, usability, gui-design, user-behavior

On my website I am using the 'Share' button to post a comment, document, or to have a poll.
I'm confused either to use 'Share' or 'Post'.

[image]

Comment: If they are posting a comment, then why not use 'Comment'. Stack Exchange has the Add Comment button doesn't it?

Comment: I want a common button for a 'comment', 'document' and 'to have a poll'.

Comment: How does comment and poll work together? And what does the document function do?

Comment: document function works for attachment

Comment: So if you click on the 'share' button, does it open up a dialog box with a text area, attachment button and polling button? Do you think it is easier to pop up the dialog rather than putting the three buttons separately? Is it a space issue or layout or something else?

Comment: I think image will give you better idea to help me with  the answer

Comment: I think Post makes more sense because you can post a comment, post a document and post your voting preference (which is in effect taking a poll). Sharing seems to imply that it is linked to other social media networks, and it is not clear whether this happens or not in your interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowadays 'Share' is understood as sharing towards other applications or social networks. I would find it confusing to see 'Share' instead of 'Post'.

Example below while i am answering this question, the label of the button to validate my answer is 'Post Your Answer', which makes more sense to me than 'Share Your Answer'.

Answer (score 3):

**Share** is a far more human term with a clear indication that there is some relationship between you and some other people.  It implies some sort of **connection to the people that you are sharing with**.

**Post** is a publishing term with very little concept of a connection with someone.  It is **clinical** and cold.

So if your intention is to share with people, use 'share'.  If it is to share with the world (i.e. publish it), then use 'post'.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Share" would be better suited to when you are sharing already existing content with others, and "Post" would be better for making new content that is available for viewing by others.

Think of a bulletin board and the similarities between it and a social networking site for example. You would *post* the new content onto the board, but if there was something already on the board that you wanted to show to others, you would *share* it

Answer (score -1):

I'll go for "Share" instead of "Post" only because the word sharing gives me a positive feeling... For me "Post" is just neutral...